# How to stop Android Studio/Gradle from making so many copies of pre-built native libraries?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I have several very large pre-built native .so files that I pull into my Android Studio project using CMake. The build system is making multiple copies of these .so files, which increases build times and the space needed to do a build. Is there any way to consolidate or eliminate any of these duplicates?

Here's one example using libMyLibrary.so, which gets copied to all the following locations during the build process.

```
..\app\build\intermediates\merged_native_libs\developmentDebug\out\lib\arm64-v8a
..\app\build\intermediates\stripped_native_libs\developmentDebug\out\lib\arm64-v8a
..\app\build\intermediates\cmake\developmentDebug\obj\arm64-v8a
..\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\d594vb20\obj\arm64-v8a
```

This library is almost 1gb in size with debug info. and we have several of them, which is why I'm trying to optimize this process.